# Expected '}' after headers included?

Tags: c++, header-files

**Question**

Why does my C++ compiler complain:

> Parse Issue: Expected'}'  line 14

?

**Background**

I am attempting to `#include` numerous headers at the top of a C++ main file, before any namespace declaration:

```
#include "Mabbs Input.h"  
#include "Mabbs Mass and Time Estimates.h"
```

The general structure of 'Mabbs Input.h' (of course including the definitions and such):

```
bool Method A (...)  
bool Method B (...)  
bool Method C (...)  
vector Method D (...)  
vector Method E (...)  
bool method F (...)  
vector Method G (...)  

Class 1 (...);
Class 2 (...);
```

The other header, 'Mabbs Mass and Time Estimates.h' (including definitions and such):

```
double Method H (...)
```

When I try to compile the main file, however, compilation fails with the error message described above.

When I attempt to fix the problem by adding a brace on line 14, the compiler emits the same message about line 13, and also tells me there is an extraneous brace on line 14.  Lather, rinse, repeat.

What's going on?

Comment: Please form an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post exactly what doesn't work and the exact error message you get (if any).

Comment: There isn't a problem with including multiple headers, unless you try to include the same header twice (e.g. header A is included by header B, and then you include both A and B in the main program).

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand from what you've read.

Comment: Post some real code that reproduces your problem. But it really looks like a simple typo.

Comment: Mat, Does this solve the problem?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ, I was wondering if the headers had to have derived classes, or friends to guard headers

Comment: Header file inclusion works *exactly* (well, modulo a couple of corner cases that don't concern us here) as if you had copied the entire contents of the header file, *verbatim*, into the including file, replacing the `#include`.  There are no constraints on what is in the header file, except that a header file can't begin or end in the middle of a string literal or `/*` comment.

Comment: In order to diagnose a syntax problem like this, we need to see *your actual code* and not some vague approximation to it.  In this case, the thing you provided as a vague approximation is so thoroughly ill-formed that I suspect you need quite a bit more help than we can reasonably provide; you need a textbook and/or an in-person tutor.

Comment: I can't remember that I ever seen spaces in a header file name before. Maybe I am just old school.

Comment: Umm you do have ';' after the function declarations in the header right? as in `bool Method A (...);`

Comment: @CyberSpock It's odd, yeah, but it shouldn't be a problem for any current C compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change a couple of settings on the xCode interface for it to work. Also, the last method did not have a semicolon on it.

Comment: It sounds like the missing semicolon was the problem.